# /etc/hosts block or redirect domain

Tags: redirect, hosts

I tried blocking domains like this:

```
127.0.0.1 https://facebook.com
127.0.0.1 https://www.facebook.com
```

But FB open correctly. How can I block or redirect websites on this file?

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/hosts` contains hostnames, not URLs. Try

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com www.facebook.com
```

Comment: it doesn't work. FB is open correctly

Comment: @Konfus2234, then your browser is probably bypassing the local system's `gethostbyname` function and using its own resolver configuration. Firefox is known to use dns-over-https, which would have this effect. It's probably better to block facebook at browser level anyway – instal an adblocker (I usually use uBlock Origin – beware, there are several uBlock something, but uBlock Origin is the correct one) and add facebook to the blacklist.